# Autoscaling Postgres Database using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql

Is it possible to autoscale a Postgres Database using Kubernetes ?
I usually run a Docker container with very specific settings to install a postgres database for my application. Does using Kubernetes to provision this db container help with scaling, load balancing if all the replicas would point to the same volume on the host server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Postgres cluster using k8s StatefulSets.
take a look at this [example](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/kubernetes-postgresql/).